# Using additional XSD in python-zeep

Tags: python, xsd, wsdl, zeep

I'm want to call web service, it returns a base64 encoded string, which contains XML document. Here's part of wsdl.

```
<xs:complexType name="method1Response">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

I have XSD schema for this response, in a separate offline file (wsdl not contains this schema). I need to parse web service response to dictionary or class instead of a raw string.

Is there a way to do it with zeep?